# Jacobian as matrix representation of a linear function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Suppose that $\mathbf{f}: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is a linear map with matrix representation $A$, then $D\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})= A$ in every point $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

$D\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})$ is the Jacobian matrix of $\mathbf{f}$ in $\mathbf{a}$.

What I tried:

If we place the origin of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in $\mathbf{a}$ and the origin of $\mathbb{R}^m$ in $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})$, there will be a good linear approximation of $\mathbf{f}$ around $\mathbf{a}$, which is the origin of the domain now. We have following linear function: $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})+ D\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})\cdot(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}) = D\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})\cdot\mathbf{x}$ (since $\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{0} \,\&\,\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})=\mathbf{0}$). Now let's consider the set $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ of basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now we have $\mathbf{f}(e_i)=D\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})e_i, \forall i=1,\dots,n.$ It's clear now that $A = D\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})$, for all points $\mathbf{a} = \lambda_1 e_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n e_n$, with $\mathbf{f}$ a linear function.

Is this a legitimate proof? Thanks for checking.

Comment: You can just verify that $L(x) = Ax$ satisfies the definition for a linear map $L$ to be the (Frechet) derivative of $f$ at $a$ (for any $a$). By uniqueness of the derivative, $L = Df(a)$.

Comment: Or more simple-mindedly, $\mathbf f(\mathbf x) = A\mathbf x$, and therefore $f_i(\mathbf x) = \sum_j A_{ij}x_j$, from which it is easy to calculate $\frac {\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}$.

Comment: As for your question, sorry to be mean, but your proof is so poorly stated that after much struggle, I am still not sure what you are trying to say. You appear to be assuming what you are supposed to prove, and in the end after not bringing up $A$ anywhere before, you simply proclaim that $A = D\mathbf f(\mathbf a)$